# Customize Chrome auto-completion in address bar?

Tags: google-chrome

is there a way to customize Chrome's auto-completion? For instance it doesn't show past urls correctly:

Here some examples of very often visited urls:

1. it shows visited url thepiratebay.se/browse/201/0/9/0 for sequence '201' but its not showing thepiratebay.am/browse/201/0/9/0
2. it shows foo.com/A/B for sequence 'foo' but it doesn't show foo.com:4000/something else. It also doesn't offer it for the sequence '4000'

That are just a few examples but its obvious to me that something is wrong.

I guess I have to tweak the sources of Chromium, right. Because I can't find in the settings. To no surprise, Firefox doesn't have problems with this at all.

well, thank you for any hint!
g

Comment: Can you get the expected URL for any typed sequence? Is the expected URL in the auto-complete list somewhere? Are there other results that are perhaps deemed more "relevant" above it?

Comment: no, it shows anything else but not related. what's really weird is that it shows some urls by typing the port correctly and some not.